# Visual Studio 2015 no projects in new project window

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After installing VS2015 File -> New -> Project has an empty list of projects.  Looked at Tools -> Extensions & Updates... and that throws an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.  Tried a repair install, same issue.  Uninstalled and re-installed, same issue.

This was a clean install of VS2015 (no prior RC), I have VS2010 and VS2012 installed (OS is Windows 8.1 64 bit, latest patches to everything).

Saw posted issues with overwrite of RC version and tried those fixes: deleting the 14.0 folder under users local and roaming (it just recreates them) and Run: devenv /clearcache devenv /updateconfiguration (no effect).

Tries reporting the issue to M$ and their website threw an error too: "The system has encountered an unexpected error. We apologize for the inconvenience. The issue will be addressed as quickly as possible."